# error: unmappable character for encoding Cp1252

Tags: java, android, opencv, encoding, character-encoding

I'm trying to compile an android translator app from GitHub ([Link of the App](https://github.com/artetxem/mitzuli)) which is about 4 years old project. I have upgraded its dependencies to **`androidx` API 29** also dependent modules i.e. OpenCV, configured `OpenCV 3.4.3`. For all modules, I have set `minSdkVersion` to 14 or above and compile & target SDK version is now 29. Everything seems to work But its showing error for character encoding.
As its translator app, it converts characters of different languages to ASCII. For that, it has a class named `Asciify.java` ([Asciify.java file link](https://github.com/artetxem/mitzuli/blob/master/libraries/lttoolbox-java/src/main/java/org/apertium/charlifter/training/Asciify.java)). The character set of this file, as well as other files, is UTF-8. But the `Android Studio` gives an error

> error: unmappable character for encoding Cp1252

I search over the internet and read some articles/answers that suggested to change the encoding to compatible encoding. I tried to change the character set to windows-1252, US-ASCII but `Android Studio` shows Incompatible Encoding as

> File 'Asciify.java' most likely isn't stored in the 'US-ASCII' encoding.
>   Why: BY_BYTES
>   Current encoding: 'UTF-8'

And the same is for windows-1252. I even tried to load these character sets forcefully But the android studio does nothing. Instead of reloading If I try to convert from one character set to another it corrupts the file. So my question is how can I fix this encoding error?

Thanks in advance.